# Performance of JVM function call vs. returning from native method?

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

Say, we have a native loop that must call some login on a JVM object from time to time:

```java
class UsesNative {
  void hangle() {...}
  void loop() {
    while (true) {
      if (doNative()) {
        handle();
      }
    }
  }
  native boolean doNative();
}
```

How is it performance-wise compared to calling `handle()` directly from the native code:

```c
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_UsesNative_doNative(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
  jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "UsesNative");
  jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, class, "handle", "()V");
  // Loop has moved from Java to native
  for (;;) {
    if (condition) {

      (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, instance, method);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Horrific. You are looking up both the class and the method every time around the loop. Don't do this.

Comment: You should move both lookup operations out of the loop. Then, the performance likely is the same as with the first variant. You are switching the context from native to Java back and forth with each iteration in either case. There might be a difference if `condition` evaluates to `false` very often.

Comment: Updated the code. I did so to simply things as much as possible, in real world it all happens even earlier, in JNI_OnLoad(), but I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Some JVMs support streamlined [fast JNI calls](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/improvements#faster-native-methods). In such case, if **doNative()** method answers the limitations of [FastNative](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/annotation/optimization/FastNative.java) or [CriticalNative](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/annotation/optimization/CriticalNative.java), the first way (no C-to-Java call) will perform better.

On the other hand, as @Holger noted above, calculation of **condition** may have more effect on the result.

Finally, the remark by @EJP about reusing the results of **FindClass()** and **GetMethodID()** is very important. These calls are extremely slow and should never be performed in a loop.

Comment: Note that these special JNI methods do not happen automatically. On ART, we use annotations. Other JVMs require different ways to mark them.